# apt-get repos for Ubuntu 12.1

Tags: apt

I have a Magento 1.9 installation which was working years ago when it was installed on Ubuntu 12.1. Since then there have been so many updates to Ubuntu itself, php (5 to 7) and mysql etc that it is bust so much I can't even log into admin. I do need access though in order to help the clean install on a new machine. So, this is a perfect job for a VM - I spun one up from the archived 12.1 ISO and am good to go, except ... I'm missing the tools I'm familiar with, which I'd normally just apt-get install after the Ubuntu install (like "mc").

So what I'm looking for is somewhere to add into it /etc/sources so that this works, instead of what I'm seeing. Thanks.

```
root@MagentoLegacy:~# apt-get install mc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 mc : Depends: libssh2-1 (>= 1.2.8) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
root@MagentoLegacy:~#
```

(Edit) Here's /etc/apt/sources.list - I added the last line after Googling for a solution, the rest is pristine:

```
#

# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 12.04.5 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20140806.1)]/ dists/precise/main/binary-i386/
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 12.04.5 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20140806.1)]/ dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 12.04.5 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20140806.1)]/ precise main restricted

#deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 12.04.5 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20140806.1)]/ dists/precise/main/binary-i386/
#deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 12.04.5 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20140806.1)]/ dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/
#deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 12.04.5 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20140806.1)]/ precise main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Ubuntu's
## 'extras' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
# deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
# deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main

deb http://www.tataranovich.com/debian precise main
```

(Edit) Here's what apt-cache has to say:

```
root@MagentoLegacy:~# apt-cache policy mc libssh2-1
mc:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3:4.8.18-1
  Version table:
     3:4.8.18-1 0
        500 http://www.tataranovich.com/debian/ precise/main amd64 Packages
     3:4.8.17-1 0
        500 http://www.tataranovich.com/debian/ precise/main amd64 Packages
     3:4.8.16-2 0
        500 http://www.tataranovich.com/debian/ precise/main amd64 Packages
     3:4.8.16-1 0
        500 http://www.tataranovich.com/debian/ precise/main amd64 Packages
     3:4.8.15-1 0
        500 http://www.tataranovich.com/debian/ precise/main amd64 Packages
     3:4.8.14-1 0
        500 http://www.tataranovich.com/debian/ precise/main amd64 Packages
     3:4.8.13-1 0
        500 http://www.tataranovich.com/debian/ precise/main amd64 Packages
     3:4.8.12-1 0
        500 http://www.tataranovich.com/debian/ precise/main amd64 Packages
     3:4.8.11-1 0
        500 http://www.tataranovich.com/debian/ precise/main amd64 Packages
     3:4.8.10-1 0
        500 http://www.tataranovich.com/debian/ precise/main amd64 Packages
libssh2-1:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
root@MagentoLegacy:~# ^C
```

Comment: Do you mean Ubuntu 12.10 or 12.04.1? There wasn't a 12.1 release.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/849275/edit) by adding the correct version as montioned @Arronical and the output of `uname -a`

Comment: Sorry guys, you are of course correct - it's 12.04.5 LTS and uname -r shows 

    3.13.0-32-generic

Comment: @CarlWhalley, could you [edit] the question and add contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list` and output of `apt-cache policy mc libssh2-1`

Comment: @CarlWhalley, You seem never run `apt-get update` after you have installed Ubuntu. So connect it to Internet then run  `apt-get update; apt-get install mc`

Comment: user.dz I sure did, and did again just now to be sure. The log I get is the first "code" block in my above post.

Comment: Add the output of `apt-get update`, please.